# What should I consider when choosing a lens for beauty/makeup photos and videos?

Tags: lens, make-up, content-creation

I own a Canon M50 Mark II and I’m looking for a lens to record makeup videos and shoot beauty photography. What lens specs should I be considering to make sure a lens is well-suited for this?

Comment: Welcome to stackexhange photo! Please note that this is less a discussion board where opinions thrive and conversation leads to insight, instead the site tries to present factual answers to concrete questions and problems. This format does not work well with opinions and recommendations, unless the case is very narrow and can be answered objectively.

Comment: You would need to specify the location - is this something that you'll be recording at a dressing table in your bedroom, or maybe recording videos in a larger beauty salon?

Answer (score 3):

**I. Use the one you already have**, Probably the 15-45mm.

1. Use it on the longest focal length, at 45mm. The longer the focal length the less distorted the face is.
2. See if the distance needed for that focal length fits in your designated space. You probably have your camera next to a mirror or some makeup lights.
3. The camera will be around 1.5 meters away.

---

4. The other approach is the inverse. Define your space, and the best position on your camera, and then test the necessary zoom needed for a pleasant framing.

**II.** Only then, when you find a specific limitation on the lens you already have, you can think about getting another specific lens.

A portrait lens for that camera is around 50-85mm, but you will need significant space.

(Not asked, probably you need to focus on good lighting instead of a new lens)